# Resizing images with filling

Tags: php, image-processing

I am trying to use this class: http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

If anyone is familiar with resizing and filling the rest of the image, please help me.

The idea is, if you upload an image that is 600x600, I want to save two images: 1-600x600 and 1-300x300. So far it's working great. However, if the user chose to upload picture with size 749x1202, I want the script to make it look good in 300x300 and 600x600 where the useless space is filled with white so the image is still 600x600. The same should happen for a smaller image, e.g. 249x400.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Set the upload directory
$uploadDir = '../../htdocs/public/product_images/'.$id.'/';
$thumbDir = '../../htdocs/public/product_images/'.$id.'/thumbs/';

@mkdir($uploadDir, 0755, true);
@mkdir($thumbDir, 0755, true);


// Store the file content in a variable
$file = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Save the file to the server
file_put_contents($uploadDir . $filename, $file);

$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$uploadDir) . $filename;
$targetThumb = str_replace('//','/',$thumbDir) . $filename;
copy ($targetFile,$targetThumb);


$image = new upload($targetFile);
if ($image->uploaded) {
    $image->image_resize          = true;
    $image->image_ratio_fill      = true;
    $image->image_x               = 600;
    $image->image_y               = 600;
    $image->file_overwrite        = true;
    $image->process($uploadDir);
} 

$image = new upload($targetThumb);
if ($image->uploaded) {
    $image->image_resize          = true;
    $image->image_ratio_fill      = true;
    $image->image_x               = 300;
    $image->image_y               = 300;
    $image->file_overwrite        = true;
    $image->process($thumbDir);
}
```

I can use another way doing it, but if someone can walk me through a bit, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Instead of using PHP to resize images, I would use imagemagick and just deliver the resulting image via PHP.

Comment: this imagemagick looks pretty hard to implement, and the server I am gonna upload the site too might not support it or all servers has it ?

Comment: Well, of course you need to check first, whether imagemagick is or can be installed. It's usage is not that hard. Just use it on the command line (executed through PHP).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to scale your image with aspect ratio kept, so at least one dimension matches your requirements (i.e. you get 128x300) then create empty image (canvas) and merge these two centering the image on canvas. But I'd simply write this 128x300 px image down on disk and enforce 300x300 px container size in HTML/CSS - this is better as your files are smaller and you can easily change i.e. bg color of the canvas just by changing your CSS - with former technique, it will not be that easy if bg is not transparent (and if it is, then why not use HTML anyway)?

Comment: the main problem is because some picture are wilder and others has move height then width, which causes to looks very ugly in html where they are set with width="200" for example